# Delete elements in list that are closer than N from each other

Tags: python, list

Let's suppose I have the following list:

```
a = [0,5,10,11,15,22]
```

...and I want to make sure that the list elements are always a minimum of  5 apart from each other, **how could I do that?**

expected result:

```
[0,5,10,15,22]
```

What I tried is not very pythonic:

```
a.sort()
prev_elem = a[0]
new_list = []
for elem in a[1:]:
    if abs(prev_elem-elem) >= 5:
         new_list.append(prev_elem)
    # update
    prev_elem = elem
```

Comment: [Why are my questions on Stack Overflow getting downvotes without explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-are-my-questions-on-stack-overflow-getting-downvotes-without-explanation)

Comment: Please be more specific about how you remove elements when they're densely packed.  Also, a request for "more Pythonic" sounds more like a code review request.  Instead, please focus on one item that you feel should be done better.  Otherwise, your question simplifies to "rewrite my code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the list.
If arr[i]+5 >arr[i+1], then delete arr[i+1].
Something like the following code.

```
i = 0
while i < len(arr)-1:
    if arr[i]+5 > arr[i+1]:
        del arr[i+1]
    else:
        i+=1
```

There's definitely cleaner and more efficient ways to do this, but this should work.

Comment: +1 , but what about a = [10,5,0] ? They are all 5 apart, but your code will not get that. If you sort the list beforehand, your code should work.

Comment: Well, the code assumes that it is sorted in ascending order. For efficient code, you definitely need to sort it first. You can also sort it in descending order, and the code would just change slightly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a few very small changes to your existing code.

Lines that are changed are commented below.

```
a = [0,5,10,11,15,22]

a.sort()
prev_elem = a[0]
new_list = [prev_elem]  # <====== initialise with one element
for elem in a[1:]:
    if abs(prev_elem-elem) >= 5:
         new_list.append(elem)  # <===== append the new element
         prev_elem = elem  # <===== indented more (inside "if" block)

print(new_list)
```

This gives:

```
[0, 5, 10, 15, 22]
```

Comment: `if abs(new_list[-1]-elem) >= 5` cuts down two lines, and avoids juggling `prev_elem` in more complicated loops.

Comment: Believably so, but the purpose of this answer was to show the minimum that needed to be changed from the OP's original code. I am happy to leave it to other answers to propose the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note this is pseudo code where n is the length of the array named arr:

```
for i = 1 to n
    if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] >= 5 OR arr[i] - arr[i - 1] <= -5)
        //remove arr[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
a = [0,5,10,11,15,22]
result = []

for i, num in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0:
        result.append(num)
        continue
    if 3 <= abs(num - a[i-1]):
        result.append(num)

# [0,5,10,11,15,22] -> [0, 5, 10, 15, 22]
# [10, 9, 5, 0] -> [10, 5, 0]
# [10, 14, 9, 11, 5, 7, 0] -> [10, 14, 9, 5, 0]
```

EDIT:

I realized that it can be done simpler. Using slice and unpacking avoids index error in case of empty list:

```
result = [*a[0:1]]      

for num in a[1:]:
    if 3 <= abs(num - result[-1]):
        result.append(num)
```